# Get Date format as output in the form of y-MM-dd reactjs

Tags: reactjs, date, datepicker, format

im trying to get (y-MM-dd) format as output(only the date). Im using react npm datepicker and the code im following is:

```
const [dateValue, onDateChange] = useState(new Date());

<DatePicker
              onChange={onDateChange}
              value={dateValue}
              minDate={new Date()}
              format="y-MM-dd"
            />
```

Output of this code is: Thu Oct 28 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-date-picker), the `format` prop only controls the **input** format and not the **output** format. Thus, the state variable `dateValue` will contain a `Date` object with no specified format.

When you want to display the date, you can pick a format by either using one of the built-in "toString" functions (such as [`toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)) or use a library such as [moment](https://github.com/moment/moment) to format the date using a custom date format as follow:

```
moment(dateValue).format("y-MM-dd");
```

Comment: dateFormat doesnt work. it has to be format="y-MM-dd". Plus im sending the date to backend throught API and the format in which it should go is "y-MM-dd"

Comment: Can you link to the exact datepicker library you are using?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-date-picker?__cf_chl_captcha_tk__=pmd__BesddRK7tlBGxc0jfbLTydfphbKmjJlBnbdNm1.LIs-1634893479-0-gqNtZGzNAyWjcnBszQe9

Comment: My bad, I assumed the wrong library. Where exactly do you get the output you shared in the question? Is it when you try to display the `dateValue` variable?

Comment: yes on displaying dateValue I get the output of: Thu Oct 28 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0500 (Pakistan Standard Time)

Comment: I have updated my answer to explain how you can format the output, since the `format` prop does not control that. The documentation clearly states that it's the **"Input format"**